Operations on Sub Lists
Let us assume that I have the following list of lists:
foo = {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}};

and that I want to multiply the elements of each sub list by the other elements of the same sub list, and then get the sum of all of them. What I have come up with (which works) is the following:
Total[Apply[Times, #] & /@ foo]

My guess is that there's a simpler and/or more elegant and/or clever way to achieve what I want in Mathematica and I'm looking for some examples of such.
Thanks!

One simplification is to use the "operator form" of Apply: Total[Apply[Times] /@ foo]

or Total[Times@@@foo], see MapApply

Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Dot @@ Transpose@foo
